# Touch Trackball Control

Tags: three.js

I try to make touch control. And i whant to make it in TrackballControls.js, so i make it like this:

```
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', mouseup, false );

function touchstart( event ) {
    if (event.touches.length != 1) return;

    var touch = event.touches[0];
    event['clientX'] = touch.clientX;
    event['clientY'] = touch.clientY;
    event['button'] = 0;
    userLog('touchstart');
    mousedown( event ); 
}
function touchmove( event ) {
    if (event.touches.length != 1) return;

    var touch = event.touches[0];
    event['clientX'] = touch.clientX;
    event['clientY'] = touch.clientY;

    mousemove( event ); 
}
```

And i have come to bat with the work spase. Page is divided into several areas. Canvas init in "Working Area"
[image]
But after than on ipad any touch treated as touch in "Working Area". If it will be usefull i can post init() function, or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

renderer.domElement - working area, which you need